# pytest hangs after collecting if I run all tests

Tags: pytest

I have some tests for implementation of my linear algebra functions.
I can run each test function separately in PyCharm or using the command e.g.

```sh
    pytest tests/test_linalg.py::test_transpose
```

But when I try to run all tests using command `pytest`, I have the following output:

```sh
    platform win32 -- Python 3.6.8, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
    rootdir: C:\some\path\to\project
    collected 6 items
    
    tests\test_linalg.py .....
```

And it hangs on this moment. If I stop it using `Ctrl + C`, it outputs that `6 passed in 55.14s` (55 seconds is how much time I waited until pressing `Ctrl + C`). I'm sure the tests don't contain difficult calculation and should be completed within several seconds. BTW I have exactly 6 test functions. Also, I tried to comment out all tests except for the first one and still observed the problem. The beginning of the test file:

```py
import numpy as np
from source.example.linalg import *
from sympy import *


def test_transpose():
    x = np.array([[0, -2, 7], 
                  [12, 3, 8], 
                  [-4, 9, 0],
                  [7, 6, -1]])
    expected = x.T
    actual = transpose(x)
    assert np.isclose(actual, expected).all()
```

Comment: What is your folder tree?
What happens when you run `pytest -sv` in the root directory?

Comment: @RyanBurch Thank you! I ran `pytest -sv` and found out that pytest for some reason runs tests on a library I import (sympy). I changed `from sympy import *` to `from sympy import Matrix` and it solved my problem